# Can I see who is following a tag?

Tags: support, tags, users, privacy

For example, there are currently 6 people following [mojibake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mojibake).  I'm one of them, is there a way to see the other 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

See [this declined feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54631/make-public-interesting-and-ignored-tags) to make the data available in the data dumps, which states that the data is not public:

> If I have data on SO that is not visible to others, I have a very reasonable expectation that that data will not be made public in database dumps. I've already entered that information with an expectation of privacy. That's not something you can just 'reverse'.